# Реклама в Android приложении

Tags: android

**Возможно ли добавить рекламу в свое приложение, если нету регистрации в `Google Play` аккаунта разработчика?**

И если да - то бросьте ссылку пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить рекламу возможно даже если нет Гугл аккаунта, не объязательно использовать Admob.

Google Play нужен для размещения APK приложения.
На [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/225101/) про некоторые из них говорится

А вообщем вот хороший сайт для монетизации Android и iOS [Appodeal](http://www.appodeal.com/+375984484573846fe275792139c2e8af), после перехода жмешь регистрация вроде и все, тех поддержка всегда на связи, все есть и денег можно много зарабатывать.

Comment: Очень хотелось бы ссылку на подобные сервисы

Comment: @Денис, обновил ответ

Comment: Даже для AdMob не обязательно иметь аккаунт разработчика в гугломаркете.

Comment: Appodeal теперь хотят чтобы у вас был аккаунт admob и доступ к нему.

Comment: @EvgenyKaravashkin, В смысле?, а зачем им это, просто мои приложения без адмоб работают

Comment: ну вот ввели они такие правила, вот тут они пытались объяснить зачем http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=658156
что-то про то что admob это основная заполняющая сеть. Причем и выплаты от admob уже через аккаунт адмоба идут.